# How to remove multiple source files after wildcard Makefile

Tags: makefile, wildcard

The question is:

I have a makefile called A.mk (a general makefile for all projects). Over there, I have added all source files in folder src1 using 
Var += $(wildcard src1/*.c)

Then, for a specific application I have a makefile (called B.mk), which includes A.mk in itself. Now, I want to substitute the source file foo1.c from folder src1 with a new one foo2.c from folder src2. How can I do that?

How can I do that if I want to substitute (or even delete) multiple files from Var in B.mk.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You new edit makes it sound like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why would B.mk need to change the sources defined in A.mk? Please edit your question and clarify what you are trying to do with these two makefiles, are they separate projects or is B a submodule?

Answer (score 2):

Make has a number of [string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions), `filter-out` looks like it would apply here

```
# All .c files
Var := $(filter-out %.c,$(Var))

# A specific file
Var := $(filter-out src/foo.c,$(Var))
```

Comment: It tried your solution, it doesn't work for me. Maybe I have not described it clearly. So, I edited the question.